# What is the meaning of "??" in swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

I came across a syntax in Swift where double question marks are used ("??").

For instance, `let val = something["something"] as? String ?? nil`

What exactly does this mean? What are some use cases for this syntax?

Comment: it is called nil coalescing operator but if you pass `nil` it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Note that your resulting object will be optional String

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72

Comment: This is an `operator`, and that mean `or`. You can use this operator when optional value missed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Nil-Coalescing Operator**

It's kind of a short form of this. (Means you can assign default value `nil` or any other value if `something["something"]` is `nil` or optional)

```
let val = (something["something"] as? String) != nil ? (something["something"] as! String) : "default value"
```

The nil-coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must match the type that is stored inside a.

The nil-coalescing operator is shorthand for the code below:

a != nil ? a! : b
The code above uses the ternary conditional operator and forced unwrapping (a!) to access the value wrapped inside a when a is not nil, and to return b otherwise. The nil-coalescing operator provides a more elegant way to encapsulate this conditional checking and unwrapping in a concise and readable form.

If the value of a is non-nil, the value of b is not evaluated. This is known as short-circuit evaluation.

The example below uses the nil-coalescing operator to choose between a default color name and an optional user-defined color name:

```
let defaultColorName = "red"
var userDefinedColorName: String?   // defaults to nil

var colorNameToUse = userDefinedColorName ?? defaultColorName
// userDefinedColorName is nil, so colorNameToUse is set to the default of "red"
```

See section [Nil-Coalescing Operator here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

Comment: `let val = something["something"] as? String != nil ? something["something"] as! String  : "default value"`

Comment: Thanks, I missed it, updated the answer.

Comment: Updated with `"default value"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This operator is generally used to provide a default value when an expression or variable produces an optional result. for ex:

```
let i: Int? = 5
let j: Int? = nil

let value1 = i ?? 9 //value1 will be 5 non-optional
let value2 = j ?? 9 //value2 will be 9 non-optional
```

You can chain multiple of these operators as such:

```
let value3 = j ?? i ?? 9 //value3 will be 5 non-optional
```

The chain terminates whenever a non nil value is found. The result of the expression will be a optional/non-optional depending on the type of last expression in the chain.

The example you've provided, although syntactically correct, is redundant, as omitting the `?? nil` would have no result on the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is `Nil-Coalescing Operator` in Swift.

[Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

> The nil-coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.

But in your example you already using optional binding , so no need of using `??` with optional, if it fails condition then it automatically assign `nil`.

```
let val = something["something"] as? String ?? nil
```

Here, `something["something"] as? String`, already assign `nil`, if `something["something"]` fails to deliver `String`. So no need of this operator here.